# Does time to live cause race conditions in DynamoDB global tables?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, race-condition, ttl, amazon-dynamodb-streams

I'm about to migrate an existing DynamoDB database from a table in one AWS region to a global table in four regions. Here's the catch: several services depend on the time-to-live (ttl) functionality in the current database, and ttl needs to be enabled in the new global table. It seems that problems could potentially arise from enabling ttl on multiple table replicas. If ttl runs in one region, there is now a race condition between the event stream from that region and the ttl deletions in the other regions. If another replica manages to delete its own record before the event stream from the other replica arrives, what will happen? Does the second deletion attempt fail gracefully because the record is already gone? Perhaps AWS has already worked out this issue, but I can't find any documentation or question forums on this topic.

One potential workaround would be to enable ttl on one region and let the stream from that replica manage ttl in the other replicas, but I don't really like that solution, since a regional outage could halt ttl deletions completely. One of the primary reasons for having global tables is to protect against regional outages.